# Calling C system calls from JNI

Tags: winapi, java-native-interface

I am trying to make a system call, CreateProcess through JNI code base running on JAVA SDK. Will this work or do I have to use some other C call? 
The original program was written on Visual Studio, and now we are partly migrating to JAVA. I was using a WinAPI, CreateProcessW which internally called CreateProcess. And this CreateProcess had no definition, so am assuming it to be a system call.
Somebody please help. Thank you.

P.S: I have to use only C code at this stage.

Comment: Did you managed to use the CreateProcess API?

Comment: Ya, I did. I actually used mingw64 for compiling using GCC, and this package had the windows API specific files. So, I just included <windows.h> file in my code and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) is a Windows API.

In the SDK headers, it's defined as `CreateProcessA` or `CreateProcessW`.

`WinBase.h` excerpt:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateProcess  CreateProcessW
#else
#define CreateProcess  CreateProcessA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

You should be able to call `CreateProcess` from your JNI Dll written in C.

Comment: Infact I have included the whole folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include" which also includes WinBase.h
But somehow I am getting a lot of build errors, saying the definitions in WinBase.h are unrecognizable

Comment: WinBase.h is the place where the CreateProcess macros are defined. To use the Win32 APIS, include <Windows.h>

Comment: Ok Thank you. I shall try this out